# Default error messages in Grails not rendering in views

Tags: grails, message

i want get default error message in view if some error occuring while insert an user. in controller i have 2 action:

```
def openPage() {
    [user: new User(params)]
}

def save() {
    User user = new User(params)
    if (!user.save(flush:true)) {
        redirect(view:'openPage', model:[user:user])
        return
    } else {
        flash.message = "User saved"
        redirect(action:'openPage')
    }
}
```

and this is my gsp:

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${user }">
    <g:eachError bean="${user }" var="error">
        <li>${error } </li>
    </g:eachError>
</g:hasErrors>



<g:if test="${flash.message }">
    ${flash.message }
</g:if>
    <g:form action="save"> 
        Name:<g:textField name="username"/>
        <g:submitButton name="ok" value="Save"/>
    </g:form>
```

but there's something wrong and i can't see any error if I sent no values. and this is my domain:

```
String username

static constraints = {
    username(nullable:false, blank:false, unique:true)
}
```

what's is wrong with my code? pls help. and must i use this method for catching errors or it's better do it with if...else and try...catch?

Comment: i get it. i must render to the view, not redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call render instead of redirect() method if save fails:

```
if (!user.save(flush:true)) {
    render(view:'openPage', model:[user:user])
    ...
```